# Gedit, R: Syntax highlit user-defined functions?

Tags: python, r, gedit

Gedit is nice and lightweight. However, by default it won't highlight user-defined functions, only language ones.

1. why?
2. Is it possible to highlight them?

Comment: You are free to edit `/usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/R.lang`.

Comment: thats nice of you, but what? Where? How?
According to this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123932/how-do-i-style-user-defined-function-names-in-gedit
it isn't working properly. Or is it?